# Регулярное выражение для положительных дробных чисел с ограничениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Требуется проверить строку из 5 символов что она является дробным положительным числом, с разделителем "/" и ограничением до 2 цифр в числителе и знаменателе. Не допускать ноль в начале числителя и знаменателя, а также чтобы они равнялись нулю. И наконец, выделив числитель и знаменатель в группы.

Написал такое:    `^([1-9]\d{0,1})[\/]([0-9]\d{0,1})` (пропускает некоторые ненужные строки)

Примеры, которые должны проходить:

```
1/3
10/1
12/34
```

И которые проходить не должны:

```
1/904
b/3
2/a7
02/34
12/900
/3
0/33
1/
3/0
10/09
907/0
```

[демо-пример](https://regex101.com/r/0utwh0/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let rExp = /^([1-9]\d?)\/([1-9]\d?)$/gm;
let sTxt = `
Примеры, которые должны проходить:

1/3
10/1
12/34
И которые проходить не должны:

1/904
b/3
2/a7
02/34
12/900
/3
0/33
1/
3/0
10/09
907/0
`;
console.log( sTxt.replace(rExp, 'Числитель: $1 / Знаменатель: $2') );
```

Или через `match` и группы:

```js
let rExp = /^([1-9]\d?)\/([1-9]\d?)$/gm;
let sTxt = `
Примеры, которые должны проходить:

1/3
10/1
12/34
И которые проходить не должны:

1/904
b/3
2/a7
02/34
12/900
/3
0/33
1/
3/0
10/09
907/0
`;
[...sTxt.matchAll(rExp)].forEach(el => console.log(`Числитель: ${el[1]} / Знаменатель: ${el[2]}`));
```